# Find the eigenvalue of 1D system of three identical quantum wells

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

The following is the problem I need help:

[image]

Consider an electron in an one-dimensional system of three identical quantum wells mounted on a substrate and separated equally by the distance *r*, as shown in the Figure. The electron, when residing at the well *i*, can be described by $\phi_i$ with an energy $e_0$ independent of *r*, as depicted in the Figure. Since these three wells are identical, we assume the $e_0<0$ is the same for each well. However, $\phi_i$ are not the eigenfunctions, so the electron can "jump" between nearest-neighbor wells with a transfer integral $\Delta(r)=-\frac{\alpha}{r}$, where $\alpha>0$. Namely, the electron can transfer between well 1 and well 2, between well 2 and well 3, but not between well 1 and well 3.

(a) Compute the eigenvalues in terms of $e_0$ and $\Delta(r)$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions in terms of $\phi_i$.

My main question is, how can I construct the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ of this system? Furthermore, what does "transfer integral" play a role here? Can I treat it as a "potential energy" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language used in your problem uses the implicit definitions that

- $e_0 = \langle \phi_i | \hat{H} | \phi_i\rangle$ for all three wells; and
- $\Delta(r) = \langle \phi_i | \hat{H} | \phi_j \rangle$ where $r$ is the distance between wells $i$ and $j$.

  (Note, however, that there is some ambiguity with the sign $-$ it's unclear why your text defines the transfer integral as $-\Delta(r)$. You need to check where else this notation appears on your text, and adjust accordingly.)

Those specifications are sufficient to recover the matrix representation of $\hat H$ over the $\{|\phi_i\rangle\}$ basis (or, more technically, the representation of the *restriction* of $\hat H$ to the subspace spanned by that basis), and from there you can calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using standard tools.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The sign of $\Delta(r)$ may be a typo. But I have some other question about it. As you write, $\langle \phi_i | {\hat{H}} | \phi_i \rangle$, from here, it seems that $\braket{ \phi_i}{\phi_i}=1$? How do we ensure that they are orthonormal?